# How to switch layout files in Zend Framework?

Tags: php, zend-framework, layout, zend-view, zend-layout

I'm sure it's a simple one-liner, but I can't seem to find it.

How can I use a different layout file for a particular action?

**Update:** This worked for me, thanks!

```
// Within controller
$this->_helper->_layout->setLayout('other-layout') //other-layout.phtml

//Within view script
<?php $this->layout()->setLayout('other-layout'); ?>
```

Comment: Can someone fix `_helper_layout` it should be `_helper->layout`

Answer (score 62, accepted):

From inside a Controller:

```
$this->_helper->layout->setLayout('/path/to/your/layout_script');
```

(via [these docs](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.layout.quickstart.html#zend.layout.quickstart.mvc))

EDIT: I should mention that the path is relative to whatever your layout directory is (by default, it's `application/layouts/scripts/`)

Comment: Or, if the layoutpath is set correctly (`$layout->setLayoutPath('application/layouts/scripts')`), use `$this->_helper_layout->setLayout('alternative_layout')` to reference `application/layouts/scripts/alternative_layout.phtml`.

Comment: From inside a view: <?php $this->layout()->setLayout('/path/to/your/layout_script') ?>

Comment: @Travis: I wouldn't want that kind of logic in a view script unless you only got a really small number of view scripts so you know where to debug for these application critical settings.

Comment: Do you know how to switch this from the bootstrap class instead.

Comment: Best to do an absolute path if you are having problems with pathing: `$layout->setLayoutPath(APPLICATION_PATH . 'layouts/scripts');`

Answer (score 13):

You can also use like this

```
// Within controller
Zend_Layout::getMvcInstance()->setLayout('layout_name');

//Within view script

<?php $this->layout()->setLayout('layout_name'); ?>
```

Your layout must be in /layouts/scripts/ folder, otherwise you need to specify the path also. No need to write .phtml, just name of the layout