# Zend Framework 2 layouts

Tags: php, zend-framework

**EDIT** : I've found what i wanted, and config-based solution. If it can help other like me here is the link :

[The article](http://www.codesynthesis.co.uk/code-snippets/configuring-layouts-in-zend-framework-2)

It works fine :)

---

i'm using Zend framework to create websites. I would like to create an administration zone but i'm stuck with a layout problem.

So here is my problem :

In my Admin module, i've modified my **module.config.php**, like so :

```
'view_manager' => [
        'display_not_found_reason' => true,
        'display_exceptions'       => true,
        'doctype'                  => 'HTML5',
        'not_found_template'       => 'error/404',
        'exception_template'       => 'error/index',
        'template_map' => [
            'layout/layout'           => __DIR__ . '/../view/layout/layout.phtml',
            'admin/index/index' => __DIR__ . '/../view/admin/admin/index.phtml',
            'error/404'               => __DIR__ . '/../view/error/404.phtml',
            'error/index'             => __DIR__ . '/../view/error/index.phtml',
        ],
        'template_path_stack' => [
            __DIR__ . '/../view',
        ],
    ],
```

and created a folder layout with a fil layout.phtml in my module.

I've changed my **Application's module.config.php** like so :

```
'view_manager' => [
        'template_path_stack' => [
            'application' => __DIR__ . '/../view',
        ],
    ],
```

My **Application's layout.phtml** is empty and my **Admin's layout.php** is'nt.

So when i'm in **zend-cms.localhost/admin**, it's all good, my layout is fine and everithing works but when i'm in **zend-cms.localhost/**, my admin layout is still here. I've search a everywhere andevery solutions i could find where unsuccessful. I can't see what i'm doing wrong ! Any ideas ?

Thanks for your help guys :)

Comment: This may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1615956/how-to-switch-layout-files-in-zend-framework. It is a procedural process as opposed to a config-based solution however.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Curtis, i've finally managed to do what i wanted :) with a config-based solution :) i will edit my post to close it !